# Safari in iOS 7 hides CSS content

Tags: css, safari, ios7

I have a section on the following website with a paragraph written in a grey typewriter font:

http://story-architect.com/?p=1614

I can see it fine on my Mac (Safari 6.0.5) running OS 10.8.5, but somehow the new Safari on iOS 7 cannot display the text. Why is that?

Many thanks for your time!

Fabrizio

Comment: Why dont you just clear your cache and cookies and refresh the page again?

Comment: I just tried that, cleared the cache and cookies and refreshed the page, but it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the media queries, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I see by looking at your page that you found a solution to this issue. Can you post it here as an answer so we can all benefit from your awesome knowledge?  Thanks :)